# How can I build a chain of modules?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am having trouble in building a chain of modules. I can connect models manually listing all the modules but need more concise representation. The following code has been tried but doesn't work? How can I correct the codes?

```
module network(
    input signed [31:0] xi,
    output signed [31:0] yo,
    input clk,
    input reset
    );

    wire signed [31:0] x0, x1, x2, y0, y1, y2, xo;
    wire [3:1] t;
    //working code for chain of pe
//   pe u0(xi, x0, 0, y0, clk, reset);  
//   pe u1(x0, x1, y0, y1, clk, reset);
//   pe u2(x1, x2, y1, y2, clk, reset);
//   pe u3(x2, xo, y2, yo, clk, reset);
    //chain of array not working! how!
    pe p[1:4] ((xi,t), (t, x), (0, t), (t,yo),clk,reset); <- want to improve
endmodule
```

Here, pe (input,output,input,output,clk,reset).

Comment: If you are using Verilog-2001 or later you can use a "generate" statement to achieve this. You might have to vectorize the xk and yk signals though(k=0,1,2). Just look up the generate statement.

Comment: I found that the code can be modified to fit the connection nets. "wire [32*3:1] t,s;" and "pe p[1:3' ((t,xi), ((xo,t), (s,yi), (yo,s), clk, reset);". Thanks anyway for comments. The connection list was difficult to understand at first but seems to be rather logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work in all version of Verilog. In this instance the parameter PE_NUM must be an int with a value of 2 or more. A generate block must be use if a 1 pe instance is desired, which requires Verilog-2001 or SystemVerilog. Some simulators may have an hit a memory limitation when PE_NUM gets big (ex 2**16).

```
/*All Verilog*/
module network(
        input signed [31:0] xi,
        output signed [31:0] yo,
        input clk,
        input reset
        );
    parameter PE_NUM = 4; // limitation PE_NUM must be greater then 1
    wire signed [31:0] xo;
    wire signed [0:PE_NUM-2] [31:0] xN;
    wire signed [0:PE_NUM-2] [31:0] yN;
    pe p[0:PE_NUM-1] ({xi,xN}, {xN,xo}, {32'b0,yN}, {yN,yo}, clk,reset);
endmodule
```

The following is an example with generate:

```
/*Verilog-2001 or SystemVerilog*/
module network(
        input signed [31:0] xi,
        output signed [31:0] yo,
        input clk,
        input reset
        );
    parameter PE_NUM = 4; // no limitation
    wire signed [31:0] xo;
    generate
        if(PE_NUM <2) begin
            pe p (xi, xo, 32'b0, yo, clk,reset);
        end
        else begin
            wire signed [0:PE_NUM-2] [31:0] xN;
            wire signed [0:PE_NUM-2] [31:0] yN;
            pe p[0:PE_NUM-1] ({xi,xN}, {xN,xo}, {32'b0,yN}, {yN,yo}, clk,reset);
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: What does the syntax `wire [0:a] [b:0] name` mean? I've only ever seen `wire [b:0] name [0:a]`

Comment: It mean double backed. Any `[]` on the left side of a declaration is packed, any `[]` on the right is unpacked. Refer to the IEEE LRMs for Verilog and SystemVerilog for mote detail

Comment: I'm assuming that's a typo for "double packed"?

Comment: [Syntax 4.1 of IEEE.1364-2005](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~songch/download/IEEE.1364-2005.pdf#page=52) seems to suggest that the `range` (what you refer to as packed) is only allowed to appear once, at least in verilog 2005.

Comment: [This page](http://electrosofts.com/systemverilog/arrays.html) suggests its a new feature in SystemVerilog